# 'u' is prepended to all text in TextBlob

Tags: python, textblob

I am using Textblob for processing textual data.

My code is:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
wiki = TextBlob("Python is a high-level, general-purpose programming language.")
wiki.tags
```

I am getting output as:

```
[(u'Python', u'NNP'), (u'is', u'VBZ'), (u'a', u'DT'), (u'high-level', u'JJ'), (u'general-purpose', u'JJ'), (u'programming', u'NN'), (u'language', u'NN')]
```

instead of:

```
[('Python', 'NNP'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('high-level', 'JJ'), ('general-purpose', 'JJ'), ('programming', 'NN'), ('language', 'NN')]
```

What might be reason for the letter 'u' getting prepended to each word?

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.2 with Python 2.7.6 version.

Comment: converted to unicode strings.

Comment: any way to remove that?

Comment: @overlord: _Why_ do you want to remove it? The `u` signifies that it's a unicode string, which is generally a good feature (unless you intentionally do not want to support unicode). You only see the `u` when you are printing the array in this way. When you actually use the value it shouldn't display the `u` anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I now know the reason after reading john0609's comment which happened to come after my above comment. Thanks for taking time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is a unicode format representation by Python. This do not make any affect while storing the string or even doing string manipulations. More, it is better to have a sign which shows that what format are we representing and it is the convention followed by Python.

Comment: Oh, thanks for informing that Mr.john0609.